# How to use @encode() to get @"NSArray" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I'm using the runtime functions to get the type of a property (thanks to eJames for helping me to figure out this way).
The attribute string of the property looks like this:

> T@"NSArray",&,Vstuff

I need to check if the property type is an array, at the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
 - (BOOL)valueForKeyIsArray:(NSString *)key fromTagret:(id)target
{
    NSString *lowerCaseKey = [self convertToKVCKey:key];

    objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([target class], [lowerCaseKey UTF8String]);
    NSString *propertyAttrs = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];
    NSString *encodedType = @"@\"NSArray\"";

    NSRange range = [propertyAttrs rangeOfString:encodedType options:NSLiteralSearch];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

But since Apple can change the type definition string at any time, I would like to generate this @"NSArray" type string. I tried it with @encode(), but it did not work:

```
NSString *encodedType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@encode(NSArray *)];
```

So how can I generate this type string? Or is there a better way to check if this property attributes contain the array type?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check this. In Objective-C source code the variables being typed as `NSArray *` is only there for the compiler to issue warnings. It has no meaning, and does not exist at runtime. If you mis-typed an `NSArray` as an `NSString`, you would get lots of warnings when compiling, but your code would behave exactly the same when run. At runtime all that is known is that the ivar/property is "an object".

Another way to think of it, is that once Objective-C is compiled, all object references are `id` references.

Comment: Actually you are right, the object references are "id" at runtime, but this does not matter in my case. The test works for me and I my Question is, how I can generate this @"NSArray" type string, because I don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: You can get a string representation of the class of an object with NSStringFromClass([obj class]). Similarly, you can get the string representation of a class with NSStringFromClass([NSArray self]).

@encode(NSArray) produces "{NSArray=#}"

Where

@encode(NSArray) produces "@"

I'm not sure if that's what you were after, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just accept that if the runtime changes, your code will break, and move on. However, I think you might be miscategorizing ivars of type `NSMutableArray *`, `CFArrayRef`, or `CFMutableArrayRef`. You also seem to be assuming all keys correspond directly to a declared property.

The cleanest solution might be to assert that the sample object being used for the test (the target) must have a non-nil value for that key, and just grab the value and test that `[[target valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`.